# ImageResizer output stream content hash doesn't match what is expected

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, md5, imageresizer

I am writing an image processing service in C# which takes a stream as input, resize the image using the popular ImageResizer library and then save the result to AWS S3.
As part of the process I am creating an MD5 hash of the stream, which I am setting as the MD5Digest on my S3 PUT request. This means that AWS will re-hash the content and compare their MD5 with the one I provided to make sure the image wasn't corrupted in transit.

This all works great when I upload a file to my service and upload it to S3 directly, but if I resize it before uploading to S3, the hash of ImageResizer's output stream doesn't match what S3 is expecting (and yes, I'm using the hash of the resized image, not the original image)

So my question is: is there anything in the ImageResizer output stream other than the image content, and if there is, how do I get rid of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the problem.

So it turns out that even though I had set ResetSourceStream to "true" on the ImageJob object, the position of the stream was not reset to 0 before calculating the hash, which means that I was pretty much always getting the same hash.

Resetting the position of the stream manually back to 0 before calculating the hash fixes the problem.